# How to delete notification document from notifications collection in firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a notification system for my website. I can add a new notification document to the `notifications` collection when someone reacts with an emoji to the particular `blog post`.

I would like to know how to delete a notification from a `notifications` collection when someone unchecked the reacted emoji?

One solution I can think of is creating a custom notification document id like {userIDOfTheReactedUser-solutionDocumentID-emojiName}.
For example: let's say the user that reacted with emoji has user id 12345 and the blog document id is 67890, and the emoji name is "heart", so the custom notification document id will be `12345-67890-heart`. and when someone unchecked the reacted emoji, I'll call this function like: `deleteDocument(12345-67890-heart)`

```
  const deleteDocument = async (id) => {
    dispatch({ type: "IS_PENDING" })

    try {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, collectionName, id))
      dispatchIfNotCancelled({ type: "DELETED_DOCUMENT" })
    } catch (error) {
      dispatchIfNotCancelled({ type: "ERROR", payload: error })
    }
  }
```

Comment: It sounds like you have a clear idea of how to implement your use-case. What is your specific question to us about the code that you shared?

Comment: I was wondering whether there is any better way to implement this functionality?

Comment: I have one more question. Is it ok to create a document with a large custom doc id? In my case, I'm combining the user id, blog document id and emoji name; this will create a large document id.

Comment: "any better way" is really hard to answer, as it all depends on the use-cases of your app. But the code you shared looks like a pretty succinct way to delete a document from Firestore. --- If your self-generated IDs are not uniformly distributed that'll impact the write scalability of your solution. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#document_ids Whether that is OK for you, only you can answer.